# Compute $\sum |a_n|$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)a_k=\frac{n}{n+1} \quad(n\ge 2)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**Problem :**

Compute $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$

Where

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)a_k=\frac{n}{n+1} \quad(n\ge 2).$$

---

Divide both side by $n$, we have
$$\sum_k^n \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right) a_k = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Take $n\to\infty$ both side, I got $\sum a_n = 0$ Because $\displaystyle\lim\sum_k^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)a_k = \lim\sum_k^n a_k$

But it's not helpful about computing $\sum |a_n|$. Is there any nice approach?

Comment: You mean all the sums to be $\sum_{k=1}^n$ and not $\sum_{k}^n$ don't you?

Comment: And if you have a reason for the final equality I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)a_k$ for $n>0$, then $s_{n+1}-s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. In our case $$s_{n+1}-s_n=\begin{cases}\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)},&n>1\\\hfill\frac23,\hfill&n=1\end{cases}$$ so that $a_1=2/3$ and $a_n<0$ for $n>1$. Hence $\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|=2a_1-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|=2a_1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac43.$$